Why is there no v33 of @ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model?
When upgrading AG Grid to v33 the npm install failed with the following error.
npm error notarget No matching version found for @ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model@^33.

This is my package.json dependencies.
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/react": "^33.0.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^33.0.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/csv-export": "^33.0.0",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard": "^33.0.0",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/master-detail": "^33.0.0",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping": "^33.0.0",
  },


In AG Grid 33 the code has been updated to be tree shakeable so that all the individual modules that were previously published as separate npm packages can all be included in the npm packages ag-grid-community and ag-grid-enterprise respectively for community and enterprise modules.
So you can simplify your package.json to this. (ag-grid-community is a dependency of ag-grid-react so does not need to explicitly included)
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "33.0.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "33.0.1",
}

From the Migration Guide for v33

In v33 there is no longer a requirement for separate NPM feature modules to achieve tree shaking. This means we can simply export all the modules from either ag-grid-community or ag-grid-enterprise as follows:

@ag-grid-community/react is replaced with ag-grid-react
All @ag-grid-community/** packages are replaced with ag-grid-community

Apart from @ag-grid-community/locale which remains unchanged.


All @ag-grid-enterprise/** packages are replaced with ag-grid-enterprise.


Remember there is a Codemod to automate the process of updating your application code import paths so that you do not have to do this manually!
npx @ag-grid-devtools/cli@33.0 migrate --from=32

